# General approach to find continuous functions?

Tags: functions

I have two functions:

1. $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto |x|$
2. $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto 3x^2-7x^2+11x-1$

I´m not really sure how to approach the question whether these functions are continuous or not.
For the 1. because it is not differentiable at $0$ than its not continuous?
For the 2. its continuous because its differentiable?

Comment: While what you say in 2. is true, this is *not* the appropriate argument. Rather, appeal to the facts that $f(x)=x$ is continuous, constant functions are continuous, and sums, products, and constant multiples of continuous functions are continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On 2**: It is. Every differentiable function is continuous. But not every continuous function is differentiable.

**On 1**: The only problem is $x=0$. To see it is indeed continuous, you have to look at the limits  $x\to0$ for $x<0$ and $x>0$. Both limites are $0$, so the function is continuous.

Comment: [You might find this helpful :)](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Differentiability [implies](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Differentiable_Function_is_Continuous) continuity (another [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269666/how-to-prove-differentiability-implies-continuity-with-epsilon-delta-definit)), but not [conversely](http://oregonstate.edu/instruct/mth251/cq/Stage5/Lesson/Explain/contNotDiff.html).

The definition of Continuity is available [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Continuous_at_Point)

Comment: See also: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120118091404AA9vI0m

Answer (score 0):

In a metric space, like $\mathbb R$ (if it is equipped with its usual topology) it is enough to prove or check that $x_n\rightarrow x$ implies that $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$.

Off course this is not a *general approach*, but it can be applied in many cases.