# Not differentiable; continuous

Tags: calculus

I know that there are functions which are continuous but not differentiable, but are there functions which are not continuous, but differentiable?

Comment: See http://www-math.mit.edu/~djk/18_01/chapter02/proof04.html and  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269666/how-to-prove-differentiability-implies-continuity-with-epsilon-delta-definit

Comment: @ml0105 The OP is asking the opposite question to that one.

Answer (score 2):

The differrentiablility is stronger than continuity hence the answer is: no. However your question is not naive: function can have partial derivatives but be noncontinuous in a chosen point.