# Differentiable implies continuity

Tags: analysis

I am slightly confused about the epsilon-delta proof of this theorem. 
I fully understand up to the point that:
$$|f(x)-f(a)| < (|′()|+)⋅|−|$$
We then pick delta to be the  $\hat{} =min(,̂/ (|′()|+))$
Thus, $|x-a|< \hat{}$. So if 
$$|f(x)-f(a)| < (|′()|+)⋅|−|$$and $|x-a|< \hat{}$, that means that $$|f(x)-f(a)| < (|′()|+)⋅ \hat{}$$
If $\hat{} = ̂/ (|′()|+)$, we obtain cancellations and deduce that $|f(x)-f(a)|< ̂$ for any choice not equal to initial epsilon.

If $\hat{}= $, is this the correct way to obtain continuity:
$$\begin{align*}|f(x)-f(a)| &< (|′()|+)⋅|−| \\
&< (|′()|+)⋅ \\
&\leq (|′()|+)*̂/ (|′()|+) \\
&= ̂\end{align*}$$

Comment: I am using the proof on this link : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269666/how-to-prove-differentiability-implies-continuity-with-epsilon-delta-definit

Comment: Learn [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and modify your post next time.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what $\hat{\delta}$ is *equal* to. All we care about is an *estimate*:
\begin{align}
0 < |x-a| < \hat{\delta} \leq \dfrac{\hat{\epsilon}}{|f'(a)| + \epsilon}
\end{align}

Hence, we get the desired inequality of $|f(x) - f(a)| < \hat{\epsilon}$.

---

Just a small tidbit to keep in mind for the future: analysis is mostly about inequalities, not equalities. So, once you get a valid estimate, just use it.