# Does piecewise continuity of $f'$ imply piecewise continuity of $f$?

Tags: fourier-series

In stating Dirichlet's theorem on Fourier convergence, it seems standard to assume that both $f$ and $f'$ are piecewise continuous. Is it possible that piecewise continuity of $f'$ implies piecewise continuity of $f$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Differentiability implies continuity (pointwise)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269666/how-to-prove-differentiability-implies-continuity-with-epsilon-delta-definit).  So if we are saying that $f'$ is piecewise continuous, i.e. continuous on the open intervals $(a_i, a_{i+1})$ for some finite number of points $a_1, \dots, a_n$, then we are in particular asserting that $f'$ *exists* on those intervals.  Thus $f$ is continuous on those same open intervals.

Moreover, if $f'$ is continuous on some $(a, a+\epsilon]$ with a finite right-side limit at $a$, then in particular it is bounded in absolute value on that interval by some number $M$.  By the mean value theorem, $f$ is thus $M$-Lipschitz on $(a, a+\epsilon]$ and so it is uniformly continuous on that interval.  This [implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245237/extension-of-a-uniformly-continuous-function-between-metric-spaces) that $f|_{(a, a+\epsilon]}$ has a (uniformly) continuous extension to $[a, a+\epsilon]$, which is the same as saying that the one-sided limit at $a$ exists.  (You can reduce that general statement to an elementary calculus argument if you wish.)

Comment: As I understand it, piecewise continuity is not just a collection of continuous pieces, but also requires that the one-sided limits at discontinuities are finite.

Comment: @ashpool: Okay, edited to address that.